# How do I insert a value into table2 from a trigger on table1

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have 2 tables with a column name `WHO`, and I'm using these 2 tables to create a view where `FSwho.who = FStasks.who`.

If I enter a new record into `FStasks` where `FStasks.who = LIZ`, but there's no record on my `FSwho.who` table, then the trigger should insert `LIZ` into my table.

With the code below, the error I get is

> The multi-part identifier "fs_tasks.WHO" could not be bound. (I've also tried `inserted.who`)

I've scoured the interwebs and most of the solutions I've come across are about changing values on the same table. How do I go about inserting values to a completely different table?

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[FS_TASKS_TRIG]
   ON  [dbo].[FS_TASKS]
   AFTER INSERT,UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @Action as char(1);
    SET @Action = (CASE 
        WHEN EXISTS(SELECT * FROM INSERTED) AND EXISTS(SELECT * FROM DELETED) THEN 'U'  -- Set Action to Updated.
        WHEN EXISTS(SELECT * FROM INSERTED) THEN 'I'  -- Set Action to Insert.
        WHEN EXISTS(SELECT * FROM DELETED) THEN 'D'  -- Set Action to Deleted.
        ELSE NULL -- Skip. It may have been a "failed delete".   
    END) 

    if @Action in ('I','U') 
    begin


        IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM fs_who where who = WHO) BEGIN
            INSERT INTO FS_WHO (WHO)
            VALUES (fs_tasks.WHO)
        END

    end 

END
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`inserted` is a table. So try:

```
INSERT INTO FS_WHO (WHO)
SELECT DISTINCT i.WHO
FROM inserted AS i
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
    FROM FS_WHO f
    WHERE f.WHO = i.WHO);
```

And you don't need to consider @Action for this...

Comment: that did the trick, is there any reason why `inserted.who` as values didnt work when i tried that? is it the way my code was setup?

Comment: Because you weren't referencing `inserted` in your `FROM` clause.